# How to implement Spring Cloud Vault with multiple paths using different roles?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I already have Spring Cloud Vault set up to read from multiple paths that have a common role but now I have a requirement to read from multiple paths that may have differing roles. My existing `boostrap.yml` file looks like

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    vault:
      config:
        lifecycle:
          enabled: true
      generic:
        enabled: false
      uri: https://blahblahblah.com:8200
      kv:
        enabled: true
        backend-version: 1
      authentication: KUBERNETES
      kubernetes:
        role: foo_role
        kubernetes-path: ocp/kubernetes/dev/cluster
        service-account-token-file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

vault:
  paths: 'path1,path2'
```

I want to read from path1 using foo_role but then path2 using foo_role2. My app has already overridden the `VaultConfigurer` class like so:

```java
  @Value("#{'${vault.paths}'.split(',')}")
  private ArrayList<String> vaultPaths;


  @Override
  public void addSecretBackends(SecretBackendConfigurer configurer) {
    vaultPaths.forEach(configurer::add);
  }
```

but I'm struggling to find which class I need to override in order to configure each path to use its respective role. Is this even possible using this library? Thank you for your help.